# Get its parent object from the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

as follows.

```
class E
{
    exec()
    {
    }
}

let e=new E();

function call(f)
{
    //how to get e?
}

call(e.exec);//call
```

I would like to perform a series of operations in the  function to manipulate the properties of "e"

Comment: why don't you just pass `e` in parameters and then , in your `call` function, call `e.exec()`

Comment: That's not possible. Why would you want to pass a reference to a method and then get the object it belongs to?

Comment: By the time you're in the scope of `call(f)`, the reference to `e` is lost. This is impossible unless you change the function declaration to include an explicit reference to `e`.

Comment: I would like to achieve aop, so I would like to know if this can be achieved, if I can, I will reduce a lot of code, it certainly will not be passed e

Comment: @user8098620 yes its impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
call.call(e,e.exec);//call
```

You could pass the context...

Or you directly pass *e* :

```
class E {
  exec(){  }
}
let e=new E();

function call(f,p)
{
  //e=f
  f[p]();
}

call(e,"exec");//call
```